# Parse Excel formula "=a(b,c,d)" with Regex in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, excel-formula

I am trying to parse the parameters of Excel formulas like "=a(b)", "=a(b,c)", "=a(b,c,d)". 
I'd like extract the function name "a" and the parameters "b", "c" and "d".

There are loads of examples on SO to parse HTML and so forth, but none specifically for parentheses.

So far, I've got this `"=(.+)\(([^,)]*)(,[^,)]*)*\)"` but when I parse `"=a(b,c,d)"` it puts "a" in match(1), "b" in match(2) and ",d" in match(3). So "c" is lost and the comma before the "d" is a pain.

How can I parse a string like this with an arbitrary number of parameters, ideally dropping the commas?

The ability to parse "=a(b(c),d(e(f)))" would be great...

---

Edit: I know that a parser is the correct solution and I have used [Devin Cook's excellent Gold Parser](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/) with great results before.

However, the particular case I'm facing is to extract the arguments from a known Excel formula. Specifically, if the formula contains the string "=Travel(", I *know* that it will have 4 arguments and if they don't parse it's not a problem. This is simply a "nice to have" function which can fail occasionally without it being an issue.

Could someone possibly help me with a regex for "=a(b,c,d)", "=a(b,c,d,e)", etc., with the constraint that there will be **no** nested parentheses or commas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.  It's not possible to match nested expressions with a regular expression.

Comment: @Carl: That's not exactly true; .NET provides the means for matching arbitrarily nested parentheses with regular expressions. But still, I'd agree that you'd be happier with a parser for this kind of job.

Comment: @Tim Indeed, and the idea is layed out here http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/02/20/377025.aspx What I was hoping for was an actual implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?
[Regex to parse functions with arbitrary depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029048/regex-to-parse-functions-with-arbitrary-depth)

Comment: looks like we had the same problem!